# Does scikit-learn implement the SLINK algorithm for single-linkage, hierarchical, agglomerative clustering?

Tags: scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

Does scikit-learn implement [SLINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering#Faster_algorithms) for [single-linkage, hierarchical, agglomerative clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html)? I wasn't able to find that info in scikit-learn's documentation.